# On OnePlus One w CyanogenMod, how do I get better camera performance?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop, oneplus-one

How do I get better camera performance from the OnePlus One w Cyanogenmod?

Problems:

- pictures out of focus / blurry
- poor low-light shots
- flash over-exposure
- camera app doesn't have as many features as samsung s5
- no HDR mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Set image quality to 95% instead of 100%. Trust me, it helps

2) Set focus from auto to continuous (this also removes the line people get while recording videos). Leaving the focus mode on tap to focus is a great idea. It lets you pick and quickly set your focal point. Unfortunately, IF YOU DO NOT TAP THE SCREEN, SHOTS WILL BE OUT OF FOCUS.

3) Try a different camera app like Google Camera, Camera fv5, OpenCamera, Camera-Next

4) Change exposure mode from center weighted to frame average keeps the whole shot in mind when choosing exposure. Center weighted and the even more extreme spot metering are for focusing on the center of the photo.

Other more involved pain in the a** Options include:

- the best fix is to root your phone and install a custom ROM.
  Some suggested Roms are paranoid android, liquidsmooth and mahdi ROM.
  For more information on how to do this, please refer to my thread on how to get cm updates (link in signature)
- Try using manual focus and mess around with the iso settings to get better images

See more tips and a camera app comparisons @ https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/full-oneplus-one-camera-guide-including-third-party-apps.278496/